# Get color(s) from an alt.Scheme

Tags: python, altair

Is it possible to get the html colors from a (categorical) scheme?
Or is it possible to directly use one specific color from a scheme, for example if you want to use category10 colors also in titles, marks ...?

Comment: I am not sure if this can be done programmatically fro Altair, but you can at least   view all the color schemes here https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/schemes/ and if you hover over one of them you will see the HTML hex code.

Comment: Yes, that was how I did it, but it's a bit cumbersome (the hovering part mainly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altair doesn't store any information about the content of its color palates; all of this is handled by the renderer (i.e. the vega-lite.js code).

The raw source for all the vega-lite color schemes is contained in this file: https://github.com/vega/vega/blob/02d79dddb2850a24abfe6a4ebaf8823548709bb5/packages/vega-scale/src/palettes.js#L66

It would in principle be possible to write a Python API around this to extract a particular color code, but I'm not aware that anyone has written that code.

Comment: Thanks, at least I can access the colors in plain text with this.